# How to simulate a mouse up event?

Tags: unity-game-engine

There is a bug in my code: When I release the mouse out of the screen, the unity can't detect "GetMouseButtonUp", and when I move the released mouse back to the screen, it detects the "GetMouseButton" which should not.

So when the mouse out of the screen, I want simulate send a mouse up event to let the unity detect "GetMouseButtonUp".

How to simulate a mouse event?

Comment: Is this happening in the editor alone?

Comment: no, this bug only happen when I attach my webgl link to facebook apps, and play game through facebook will find it. But when I play my game through my webgl link, this would not happen. So I am very confused.

Comment: Hmm.. Can you use OnApplicationFocus(bool), and see whether it's called with a value of false when you drag move the pointer of screen? If it does, problem solved. Otherwise, might have to use Camera.ScreenToViewportPoint

Answer (score 1):

Pseudo code

```
bool mouseIsDown = false;

public void Update()
{
    Rect screenRect = new Rect(-Screen.width/2, -Screen.height/2, Screen.width, Screen.height);

    If(screenRect.Contains(Input.mousePosition))
    {
        if(mouseIsDown && !Input.GetMouseButton(0))
            OnMouseUp();

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            OnMouse();
            if(!mouseIsDown)
            {
                OnMouseDown();
                mouseIsDown = true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public void OnMouseDown()
{
    // Do something
}

public void OnMouse()
{
    // Do something
}

public void OnMouseUp()
{
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: The question is that sometimes when the mouse move out of the game then release, I can't detect the "GetMouseButtonUp". And when it move back(Already release), the unity detect "GetMouseButton" status.

Comment: Okay i think i understand now, try now

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure if I correctly understand your question. But, you can use these functions the same way you would use the `Start()` `Update()` `Awake()` etc. functions

```
void OnMouseUp () {
}

void OnMouseDown (){
}
```

Comment: I think these function only work when a GameObject have a collider component, and only work for this gameobject. Aren't they?

Comment: Yes this is true, the game object does need a collider and they will only be triggered when the mouse button is down on the game object with the script attached.